# st_transform gives inaccurate results

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I am trying to convert Cape Lo19 coordinates (EPSG:22279) to Hartebeeshoek94 Lo19 coordinates (EPSG:2048)in R using the sf package.

cape_westing = 49290
Cape_southing = 3783930

https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=22279&t_srs=2048&x=49290.0000000&y=3783930.0000000 gives the following result:

harte_westing = 49347.60
harte_southing = 3784219.62

My R code looks like this:

```
require(sf)
require(tidyverse)

example <- data.frame(x = 49290, y = 3783930) %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y")) %>% st_set_crs(22279)

transformed <- st_transform(example, crs = 2048)

transformed

Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 49350.77 ymin: 3784220 xmax: 49350.77 ymax: 3784220
Projected CRS: Hartebeesthoek94 / Lo19
                  geometry
1 POINT (49350.77 3784220)
```

As you can see, the result does not match https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=22279&t_srs=2048&x=49290.0000000&y=3783930.0000000.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a datum transformation issue.

Comment: Yup. A bug in the PROJ database used by sf?

Comment: If you have two different results, how do you know which one is correct?

Comment: The epsg.io is correct. Cross-validated with PostGIS.

Comment: If PostGIS is using the same old version of the Proj library than epsg.io it is no wonder that they give same results. It is still possible the newer Proj version is using a more accurate transformation. GDAL version 2.4.4 that is the last one in the 2.x series gives the same result than epsg.io `gdal_244>gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:22279 -t_srs epsg:2048 
49290 3783930
49347.601657782 3784219.62436444`. I checked that my GDAL 2.4.4 version is build against Proj version 6.1. You can check what your PostGIS is using with `select postgis_full_version()`

Comment: I checked that Proj version 7.1 gives the same result than epsg.io so the change is probably introduced with Proj 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These results are obtained with Proj version `Rel. 8.1.0, July 1st, 2021`

First check which transformation operations are supported. This Proj version supports only one.

```
projinfo -s epsg:22279 -t epsg:2048 --spatial-test intersects
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Inverse of South African Survey Grid zone 19 + Cape to Hartebeesthoek94 (1) + South African Survey Grid zone 19, 15 m, South Africa - mainland onshore.

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +inv +proj=tmerc +axis=wsu +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0
        +a=6378249.145 +rf=293.4663077
  +step +inv +proj=longlat +a=6378249.145 +rf=293.4663077
  +step +proj=push +v_3
  +step +proj=cart +a=6378249.145 +rf=293.4663077
  +step +proj=helmert +x=-134.73 +y=-110.92 +z=-292.66
  +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84
  +step +proj=pop +v_3
  +step +proj=tmerc +axis=wsu +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84

WKT2:2019 string:
CONCATENATEDOPERATION["Inverse of South African Survey Grid zone 19 + Cape to Hartebeesthoek94 (1) + South African Survey Grid zone 19",
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["Cape / Lo19",
            BASEGEOGCRS["Cape",
                DATUM["Cape",
                    ELLIPSOID["Clarke 1880 (Arc)",6378249.145,293.4663077,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",4222]],
            CONVERSION["South African Survey Grid zone 19",
                METHOD["Transverse Mercator (South Orientated)",
                    ID["EPSG",9808]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",19,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
                    SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8805]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["westing (Y)",west,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["southing (X)",south,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",22279]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        PROJCRS["Hartebeesthoek94 / Lo19",
            BASEGEOGCRS["Hartebeesthoek94",
                DATUM["Hartebeesthoek94",
                    ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",4148]],
            CONVERSION["South African Survey Grid zone 19",
                METHOD["Transverse Mercator (South Orientated)",
                    ID["EPSG",9808]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",19,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
                    SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8805]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["westing (Y)",west,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["southing (X)",south,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",2048]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["Inverse of South African Survey Grid zone 19",
            METHOD["Inverse of Transverse Mercator (South Orientated)",
                ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",9808]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8801]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",19,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8802]],
            PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
                SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                ID["EPSG",8805]],
            PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8806]],
            PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8807]],
            ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",17519]]],
    STEP[
        COORDINATEOPERATION["Cape to Hartebeesthoek94 (1)",
            VERSION["DSM-Zaf"],
            SOURCECRS[
                GEOGCRS["Cape",
                    DATUM["Cape",
                        ELLIPSOID["Clarke 1880 (Arc)",6378249.145,293.4663077,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",4222]]],
            TARGETCRS[
                GEOGCRS["Hartebeesthoek94",
                    DATUM["Hartebeesthoek94",
                        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",4148]]],
            METHOD["Geocentric translations (geog2D domain)",
                ID["EPSG",9603]],
            PARAMETER["X-axis translation",-134.73,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8605]],
            PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",-110.92,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8606]],
            PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",-292.66,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8607]],
            OPERATIONACCURACY[15.0],
            ID["EPSG",1504],
            REMARK["Residuals should not exceed 15 metres. Also used to transform Cape to WGS 84 - see code 1129."]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["South African Survey Grid zone 19",
            METHOD["Transverse Mercator (South Orientated)",
                ID["EPSG",9808]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8801]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",19,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8802]],
            PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
                SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                ID["EPSG",8805]],
            PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8806]],
            PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8807]],
            ID["EPSG",17519]]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["South Africa - mainland onshore."],
        BBOX[-34.88,16.45,-22.13,32.95]]]
```

Convert the test point from EPSG:22279 into EPSG:2048

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:22279 +to init=epsg:2048
49290 3783930
49350.77        3784220.03 0.00
```

The most recent Proj library gives the same result than R sf. If you know that the result that epsg.io gives is more accurate you should contact the Proj developers.

Please notice that epsg.io web site is maintained by the MapTiler company and it has nothing to do with the EPSG organization. I guess that in the background epsg.io is running a bit older version of Proj.

Comment: The implications are immense. Proj 8 may give more accurate transformations but it means a 1.5m shift from Proj 7. Imagine trying to manage heaps of data projected with Proj 7 or earlier. I really think this needs to be highlighted as a serious issue. Expecting people to fix their databases is a bit presumptious.

Comment: Do you mean an issue in R? I do understand the trouble when using data with mixture of older/newer transformations but somehow users also need to get access to improved formulas. Unfortunately I can't say how the transition could happen without any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

It seems sf is using the wrong ellipsoid parameters.

By specifying the CRS more explicitly as follows, yields the correct result:

```
example <- data.frame(x = 49290, y = 3783930) %>% 
st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y")) %>% 
st_set_crs("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +axis=wsu +a=6378249.145 +b=6356514.966398753 +towgs84=-136,-108,-292,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
```

PostGIS recognises EPSG:22279. I suspect sf is using a bad database.

Comment: Less a bug than a matter of usage, I'd think. Many interfaces require explicit transformation parameters or optionally permit overrides from default.